# What is winapifamily.h?

Tags: windows, sdk, wdk

Can't find it in Windows SDK and DDK, but some of our existing code includes it. 
The only meaningful link I found by Google is: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/hh450839%28v=vs.85%29.aspx
What's it?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is a new header file, currently only present in the SDK/DDK of Windows 8 Consumer Preview / Visual Studio 11 Beta. I think this header is for splitting the Win32 API into Desktop/MetroApp 'partitions'.

Comment: Yup, that's it.  WINAPI_FAMILY macro, checked in lots of places.

Comment: Good catch Guest but, MQ, how the heck could you post this question without mentioning that your code is building for Win8?

Comment: Hi Carey Gregory, sorry for the confusion. It's other one's code, so I don't know it's for win8.

Answer (score 9):

For reference, the **winapifamily.h** is located at `C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\shared`