# Macro to recognize WinRT?

Tags: c++, windows-8, windows-runtime

Is there a new macro to determine in code if the application is running on WinRT? As I'm working with `LoadLibrary`, it would be great if there is a macro to replace all calls to `LoadLibrary` with one to `LoadPackagedLibrary`...

I'm understanding the documentation correct as in I can load any DLL (as long as it's inside my package) via `LoadPackagedLibrary`, right?! (And as long as that DLL doesn't use black-listed APIs...)

Comment: You mean like #if NETFX_CORE?

Comment: Sorry, I guess that's for .NET. Maybe for C++ you could use [WINAPI_FAMILY](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9509166/what-is-winapifamily-h)

Comment: Well as I'm currently using only the LoadLibrary-related stuff from <Windows.h>. So via `#if WINAPI_FAMILY WINAPI_FAMILY_APP` I can determine whether or not I'm on WinRT?

Comment: Well, I have never done it, so I am not sure, but if it is your application - you should be able to tell yourself if it is a WinRT app or a WinAPI app. Unless you are asking about whether you are running on a Windows on Arm (WoA)/Windows RT tablet - then I have no idea how to check that.

Comment: Well I want to have a generic code (it's already compatible with Windows and Linux, simply based on the platform dependent macros...) Now MS replaces `LoadLibrary` for WinRT but all other functions I use are still allowed...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I recently updated to Visual Studio 2012, and think I found the answer to my question:

Inside the Microsoft Headers the Macro `WINAPI_FAMILY_PARTITION` is used to determine the "Level" of WinAPI. Currently there are `WINAPI_PARTITION_DESKTOP` and `WINAPI_PARTITION_APP`, therefore I "guess" that via this macro one can differentiate between Desktop and Metro...

The two macros lead to another set of macros: `#define WINAPI_FAMILY_APP          WINAPI_PARTITION_APP` and `#define WINAPI_FAMILY_DESKTOP_APP  (WINAPI_PARTITION_DESKTOP | WINAPI_PARTITION_APP)`. Therefore if `WINAPI_FAMILY_APP` is defined one should be able to assume that it's a Metro application...

Answer (score 2):

To add your to answer, please see this article [Dual-use Coding Techniques for Games](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chuckw/archive/2012/09/17/dual-use-coding-techniques-for-games.aspx)

In the introduction part

> Apps written for the Windows Store make use of the Windows Runtime
>   (WinRT) and a restricted subset of Win32 APIs located in the core API
>   family (indicated by WINAPI_FAMILY set to WINAPI_PARTITION_APP).
>   Traditional Win32 desktop apps have access to a larger desktop API
>   family (indicated by WINAPI_FAMILY set to WINAPI_PARTITION_DESKTOP),
>   but this is subject to various levels of OS support required for each
>   function

Answer (score 0):

Try `__WRL_WINRT_STRICT__` .  Not entirely sure that's the right one, but if you go look in that file it will probably have what you want.

From [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winappswithnativecode/thread/0d8c9bb2-ee3c-4f7f-92c4-61644d15e268) and [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh700142%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).