# How to check if my library is used for a Win8 Store app or a Win32 app?

Tags: c++, winapi, microsoft-metro, directx

As the title suggests I'm trying to build a library ( a small DirectX renderer) to be used both in a Windows8/Metro App, while also be usable for developement of Desktop apps using Win32.

To be more precise I'm wondering if I can use some sort of pre-processor directive to detect the target platform and separate the difference of code between these platforms using them, and if there exist where exactly can I get more information about that.

Comment: Please check this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11961771/macro-to-recognize-winrt

Comment: That other question might be for using inside of your own application though. If you create a library - it might be used in either Windows Store or desktop apps - not sure if that macro helps you there.

Comment: The pre processor makes compile time changes to code so will allow you to create two different versions. It won't help you detect what environment it's running in.

Answer (score 1):

You can not, once a library has been build, pre-processor directives are already processed. This is why you would have to build two librarys, one for each purpose.

This link might answer further questions:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winappswithnativecode/thread/61829316-fff3-43c7-a86a-cf0e13c66845/

Comment: My comment referred to having those directives compile two different binaries, not having a piece of compiled code that detects at runtime the environment.